# Why is my OSX Command Line Tool Binary file so big?

Tags: xcode, macos, command-line, executable

I'm making a Command Line Tool in Xcode.  I used the Project template for it.  I haven't altered the default Build Settings.

My Tool literally has 2 implementation files (in addition to main.swift).  I have no extra files packaged in the Bundle.

I have a test target with Fixtures, but their target membership is not my command line tool; just the test target.  Even so, they are small text files.

I am not linking any framework other than Foundation

The Binary executable is 10.2Mb.   I was thinking it should be around 1/10th that size.

Are there build settings I might change?  I have no idea why it's so large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the entire Swift library is embedded in the package. The evolution speed of Swift is very fast and embedding the library allows it to use different Swift versions in the same OS version.

It will be changed in the next Swift / macOS version.

Comment: Yes, the ObjC runtime is in the OS frameworks. At the moment I would write all CLIs in ObjC.

Comment: I didn't realize that the Swift runtime libraries were embedded in binary executables this way. For apps, they are all embedded as dylibs in the app bundle. I guess they are statically linked?